# ussd server sample example

Tags: jboss7.x, ss7, mobicents

I am working on jss7 project. I am trying to implement ussd server and client simple example.
I tried this example:
[Jss7 standalone example](https://code.google.com/p/jss7/wiki/StartSS7asStandalone)

but it didn't work because it doesn't use the latest version of jss7 implementation 2.1.0

i found this example:
[Jss7 standalone server example](https://code.google.com/p/jss7/source/browse/map/load/src/main/java/org/mobicents/protocols/ss7/map/load/Server.java)

It doesn't provide any error while compiling but when I run it there is a lot of errors and exceptions that I can't understand nor handling... Like:

> 1)ERROR org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.ManagementImpl  - Error while
>   persisting the Rule state in file java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>
> 2)at javolution.xml.XMLObjectWriter.write(XMLObjectWriter.java:272)
>     at
>   org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.ManagementImpl.store(ManagementImpl.java:441)
>     at
>   org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.ManagementImpl.addServerAssociation(ManagementImpl.java:741)
>     at
>   org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.map.load.Server.initSCTP(Server.java:115)
>     at
>   org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.map.load.Server.initializeStack(Server.java:89)
>     at org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.map.load.Server.main(Server.java:515)
>
> 3)log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.

So I appreciate if anyone can help.

Simply i want to run simple client server application.